# Prove that the following series converges uniformly in $E=\{z: Re(z)> \delta>0\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Prove that the following series converges uniformly in $E=\{z: Re(z)> \delta>0\}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n} e^{-nz}$$.

I have the answer, I just done understand it.
First off I have the ddefinition of the radius of convergence of a series as being $$R=\frac{1}{\lim \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$ if the series is given as $\sum a_nz^n.$
The answer right from the begining, says that since the series can be written as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n} (e^{-z})^n$$ therefore $$R=\frac{1}{\lim \sup \sqrt[n]{|\sqrt{n}|}}$$How when it's not $\sum \sqrt{n}z^n$ but $\sum \sqrt{n}e^{-zn}$? I will continue the problem, when this is cleared up. I wanna try to solve the second part myself, then ill post my troubles if they arise

Comment: You can view the series as a power series in $w$, where $w = e^{-z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\forall z\in E)  (\forall n \in \mathbb N) $

$$| \sqrt{n}e^{-nz}|\leq\sqrt{n}e^{-n\delta}$$

on the other hand

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n^2\sqrt{n}e^{-n\delta}=0$$

thus for large enough $n$,

$$0<n^2\sqrt{n}e^{-n\delta}<1$$

and

$$0<\sqrt{n}e^{-n\delta}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ convergent.

Qed.

Comment: i am the first this time.

Comment: you can use that $e^x = 1+x+\sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{x^k}{k!} > x$